# How do you disable the "sharing this tab" message in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, xvfb, webrtc

I'm using selenium to record chrome screen. And I also want to share this screen throw webrtc. When I start share a tab screen. Chrome will show this message :
https://storage.googleapis.com/support-forums-api/attachment/thread-48583572-813505606056354659.png

How to hide this message with Python + Selenium ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try registry settings. There are many possible entries, check the list here, you might find what you're looking for:

https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/

Or download the Chrome ADMX template and see if any group policies help:

https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/187202?hl=en